# Rename files in different folders removing numbers from file names

Tags: unix

I'm trying to remove numbers from file names stored in different folders. 
Specifically, I have 100 folders named: my_folder1, my_folder2, my_folder3,..., my_folder100. 
In each folder there are files named: my_folder1.txt for my_folder1, my_folder2.txt for my_folder2, my_folder3.txt for my_folder3, ...my_folder100.txt for my_folder100. I need the following output: 
my_folder.txt for my_folder1, my_folder.txt for my_folder2, my_folder.txt for my_folder3, ..., my_folder.txt for my_folder100. In other words I need to remove the numbers from file names in each folder. I used the following code:

> ```
>    for file in `find . -name 'my_folder*.txt'`; do
>    mv $file ${file/+([0-9]).txt/.txt}
>    done
> ```

but the numbers are still there. 
Can anyone help me please?

Best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for:

```
for file in */*.txt; do   mv $file $(dirname $file)/my_folder.txt; done
```